# Passing custom class variable in api call

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, arguments

I am using Amazon MWS Reports [PHP Library](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/reports/v20090901/php.html/179-8561214-1090664) and Got badly struck when requesting API with following code:

```
$parameters = array (
   'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
   'MarketplaceWebService_Model_TypeList' =>  DEFAULT_REPORT_TYPE,
   'MarketplaceWebService_Model_StatusList' =>  array(
    'FieldValue' =>'_CANCELLED_' , )
      
//   'MWSAuthToken' => '<MWS Auth Token>', // Optional
 );
 $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportRequestListRequest($parameters);
```

in `MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportRequestListRequestclass` constructor, it is defined as

```
    public function __construct($data = null)
        {
            $this->fields = array (
    'ReportRequestIdList' => array('FieldValue' => null, 'FieldType' => 'MarketplaceWebService_Model_IdList'),
'ReportTypeList' => array('FieldValue' => null, 'FieldType' => 'MarketplaceWebService_Model_StatusList'),
.......
```

I am unable to understand how should I pass my variable value? I can't understand how `'MarketplaceWebService_Model_IdList'` type of variable will be created and passed??

When I use scratchpad for this query, these two arguments are showing in the following way:

```
 &ReportRequestIdList.Id.1=49499499399 (DUMMY, INT VALUE)
  &ReportTypeList.Type.1=_GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_
```

I can't pass any of custom type (Class type variables at all, Unable to understand this).

Answer (score 0):

use the IdList class in Report API to set the format of the id list.

```
$id_list = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_IdList();
$id_list->setId($x);
```